# What is the simplification of $\frac{\sin^2 x}{(1+ \sin^2 x +\sin^4 x +\sin^6 x + \cdots)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

What is the simplification of $$\frac{\sin^2 x}{(1+ \sin^2 x +\sin^4 x +\sin^6 x + \cdots)} \space \text{?}$$

Comment: You can enclose LaTeX in `$`-signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $x \notin \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi \mathbb{Z}$ you can write $q = \sin^{2}{x}$ with $|q| < 1$ and use the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} q^{n} = \frac{1}{1-q}$.

Comment: So the answer would be sin^2 (x) . ( 1-sin^2 (x) ) ??

Comment: @Mr D: Yes, under the assumption about $x$ that I made. Note that this can be further simplified by using $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ and the formula $\sin{2x} = 2\sin{x}\cos{x}$

Comment: @Mr D: Note that you still have to consider the two cases $\sin{x} = \pm 1$

Answer (score 3):

What does $1 + \sin^2 x + \sin^4 x + \sin^6 x + ....$ simplify to?

Or better, what does $1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + ....$ simplify to?

Or better, what does $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ....$ simplify to?